# Why is it bad to have all html on a single line?

Tags: html, minify

When minifying/compressing HTML it's common to have everything on a single line.

Somewhere I've read or heard that there is a pitfall with having everything on a single line. I can't remember why.

**Example**

Like this but much longer:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Why can it be bad to have everything on a single line?

Comment: *Somewhere I've read or heard* .. where?

Comment: @Mr.Alien If I already now that, I would not need to be asking this here, would I?

Comment: [So we search again?](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=is+it+good+to+minify+html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technical reason is inline and inline-block elements behave differently if they are separated with space or newlines. Once I had `li` tags set to `inline-block`, and in my static version they were separated with newlines and on webpage they appear one each line but when it was generated with php they were all in one line which caused the `li`s to appear all in one line. Similarly `span` tags having spaces amongst each other have actual word-spacing in visual output of webpage.